# What are the prerequisites for learning WCF?

Tags: wcf

I was recently working on .net; now I want to learn WCF. Are there any topics required before going to WCF? Because somewhere I saw that WWF is necessary, is it? I want to go through the [WCF tutorial](http://www.wcftutorial.net/IntroductionToWCF4.0.aspx).. please suggest me a right path

Thank you

Comment: At least tag it `[wcf]` and not `[asp.net]`...

Comment: Just get a WCF book and start reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book I always recommend to get up and running in WCF quickly is [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) by Michele Leroux Bustamante. She covers all the necessary topics, and in a very understandable and approachable way. This will teach you everything - basics, intermediate topics, security, transaction control and so forth - that you need to know to write high quality, useful WCF services.

[image: Learning WCF]

The more advanced topics and more in-depth look at WCF will be covered by [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) by Juval Lowy. He really dives into all technical details and topics and presents "the bible" for WCF programming. He just recently completed a [third edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489), which covers WCF in .NET 4 and AppFabric and the Azure Service Bus, too.

[image: Programming WCF Services]

As for other resoures: there's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, check out the [screen cast library up on MSDN](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) for some really useful, 10-15 minute chunks of information on just about any topic related to WCF you might be interested in. Also, on CHannel9, check out the [Endpoint TV Show](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212010240/https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint) - the older videos in this show are really good intros to WCF (create your first WCF service, create your first WCF client and so forth)

Comment: @Marc..Thank you so much for your valuable information. i heard many times AppFabric and Azure services..what are they, are they technologies like WCF?

Comment: @Mihir: [Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure/) is Microsoft's offering of "computing in the cloud", e.g. they run the datacenters full of servers for you, you just deploy your apps (and WCF services, if you want) to their machines and run them - no fuss with buying and setting up servers, no problem when you suddenly need a few more servers etc.

Comment: @Mihir: [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) is a management and caching solution for your own server-based WCF and WF solutions, and it also has an Azure version available